# Pass subclasses to a function that takes their superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, parameters, subclass

Let's say I have three classes - `Animal`, `Cat` and `Dog`, where `Cat` and `Dog` are subclasses of `Animal` (this does sound like the first lectures, but it's not homework I promise, just simplifying the real code)

```
Dog* spike = new Dog(); 
Cat* puss = new Cat();   

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    function(spike, puss);
    return 0;
}

void function(Animal *pet, Animal *pet2)
{
   magic->andSoForth();
}
```

Now this generates the following error:

```
Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Dog *' to 'Animal'
  No constructor could take the source type,
    or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Changing the parameters to exactly match generates similar errors, only that it says it can't convert from a class to the same class.

I have successfully called the subclasses functions and members that they inherit from the superclass, so I know that this, logically, should work. I just don't know in what twisted way this language want me to bend logic.

**EDIT**

Solution happen to be: pointers confuse everyone.

- Declare pointers.
- Send pointers as arguments to a function that does NOT handle pointers.

In my example, I sent the "not-pointers" to the function that wanted pointers, I just switched that. Now it works fine.

Comment: Checked edit history — the first version had `Dog spike` but then was changed to `Dog* spike`. It was probably incorrect in the beginning, but seing the incorrect code in the question is critical to understand the difference between it and correct code in the answer. Can anyone elaborate on why this change happened and was top answer given based on it or on the first version of the question?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is how it should look.

```
Dog* spike = new Dog();
Cat* puss = new Cat();

function(*spike, *puss);

void function(Animal pet, Animal pet2)
{
   //magic
}
```

Tested and working.

Comment: The problem with this is that it forgets that, for example, `pet2` is a `Cat`.  In this case it's not a huge deal, because the animals don't actually do much if anything.  But later on, when a `Cat` includes custom behavior and properties, or if you want to squirrel one away in a vector or something, you'll experience the "slicing problem" firsthand.  The correct answer involves figuring out why the pointer version breaks; it should not be as complicated as you're making it out to be.

Comment: Or, declaring the function to take references.  That'd be better than pointers, but still doesn't fix the reason why you're currently stuck passing `Animal`s by value.  And you need to figure that out; with C++, you don't get polymorphism unless you access an object through a pointer or reference.  Without polymorphism, subclasses become rather useless.

Answer (score 7):

When you dynamically allocate a new object, you get a pointer to that object. So you need to store it in a pointer like so:

```
Dog* spike = new Dog();
Cat* puss = new Cat();
```

You can then pass `spike` or `puss` for any parameter of type `Animal*`, assuming `Dog` and `Cat` do indeed inherit from `Animal`. This is the basics of polymorphism in C++:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `D`”, where `D` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `B`”, where `B` is a base class (Clause 10) of `D`.

You could, of course, have stored them right away as `Animal*`:

```
Animal* spike = new Dog();
Animal* puss = new Cat();
```

Don't forget to `delete` them. Better yet, don't use `new` at all:

```
Dog spike;
Cat puss;
void function(const Animal&, const Animal&);
function(spike, puss);
```

Comment: I do actually declare them as pointers in the real code, sorry I was sloppy doing the mock-up :) I tried to change them to Animal as suggested, but it made no difference. Still the same error :/

Comment: @XistenZ Append to your question the actual code and the line that the error says it corresponds to.

Comment: @XistenZ Your edit does not explain what you did to fix it. Show what was wrong and the code that fixed it. Also, put the answer in your answer, not in the question. :) Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's *reasonable* to assume that the problem you have is assigning a pointer to a non-pointer, or vice versa. But your code **is not the real code**, and your error messages are apparently **not the real error messages**. So it's all guesswork, in particular those already-posted answers that say "this is it" (it probably is, but not necessarily, and the uncertainty is entirely your own fault).

---

EDIT: the OP changed the question's code 10 seconds after I posted this.

The code still does not square with the purported error message.

I'm not going to chase this question as it changes.

---

Now, as to what to do…

---

Don't use `new`.

Experienced C++ programmers sometimes use `new` in controlled ways, wrapped in suitable code. Incompetent C++ programmers often use `new` as a matter of course. But in general, you don't need it, and it's problematic, so better as default don't use it.

Then, your program (which you neglected to show) would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Animal {};
struct Dog: Animal {};
struct Cat: Animal {};

void function(Animal const& pet1, Animal const& pet2 )
{
   //magicAndSoForth();
}

int main()
{
    Dog spike; 
    Cat puss;

    function( spike, puss );
}
```

Comment: I neglected to show my program since I'm just after the principle. I do send parameters when creating the different classes, can you do that with structs? Don't know much about them yet, except they're confusingly alot like classes, but uglier.

Comment: @XistenZ But uglier? I'm all ears (Hint: "C++" != "C#", not even `string.Equals("C++", "C#", StringComparison.UniversalPolyglotIgnoreInterpunction)`)

Comment: They are, for all meaningful purposes, entirely identical to classes.

Comment: @XistenZ I don't know what your sources are, but rest assured, structs are as ugly as classes are. The only difference between the two is that one has public visibility by default, and the other has private.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to offend anyone ^^ I meant ugly just visually, can't really explain how though.

Comment: @XistenZ: In C++, structs *are* classes.  Literally, the only differences between a struct and a class are the default visibility (public for structs) and the use of `struct` rather than `class` to declare the type.  In every other respect, they are identical.  Even inheritance, virtual functions, and all that classy stuff; structs can do all that too, identically.

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype for `function` almost certainly says

```
void function(Animal pet1, Animal pet2);
```

or something very similar to that.  (I know you have a prototype, since `function` appears after `main`.  If you hadn't forward-declared it, C++ would complain that it couldn't find `function` at all, not that it's taking the wrong types of args.)

Problem is, your real `function` takes pointers.  And since `main` appears before the real `function`, it doesn't see that.  It only sees a declaration of one that takes actual `Animal`s, so it tries to use that...but fails, because an Animal pointer is not an Animal.  (The real `function` differing from the prototype is fine with C++, due to the possibility of overloading.  As far as the compiler knows, `function(Animal, Animal)` exists in another translation unit, and you're just defining `function(Animal*, Animal*)` too.)

Look through your code for the declaration of `function`, and make it say

```
void function(Animal *pet1, Animal *pet2);
```

to match up with the actual function's signature.

**PS:** this would have been so much easier to figure out if you had included all the relevant declarations.

**PPS:** A better idea would be to take references instead, as [suggested by Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673445/319403).  But in order to do that anyway, you'd have to fix the prototype mismatch (or make the real function appear before code that uses it) first

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you need to do is this

```
Animal *spike = new Dog();
Animal *puss = new Cat();
```

Basically, all your pointer definitions must be of the base class, and these may be initialized with derived class pointers.

Comment: Do you mean `Animal *spike`?

Comment: Sorry, it is Animal * Spike, my mistake, Ive edited it in now..Thanks @Xymostech